# use string for IN operator

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to match a comma separated list of ids against another table.

This works:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE id IN (2,3))
```

And this works:

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE id = a.tag)
```

So, how do I combine the two? (this does NOT work)

```
SELECT * FROM a WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM b WHERE id IN (a.tags))
```

Do I have to wrap "a.tags" in some function? Is there some equivalent to eval or explode?

How do I get this to work?

Comment: comma separated list always has a sql code smell.. Normalization would be the ultimate answer.  MySQL has a FIND_IN_SET function for searching in CSV data  read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set.. This is the best hint i can give without knowing table structure or example data.

Comment: This looks really helpful, probably the answer I need: SELECT DISTINCT id FROM a, b WHERE (SELECT FIND_IN_SET(b.id,a.tags)), would be nice to know if the above is possible, but will happily accept this as the answer.